# Laravel return Redirect::to not working outside action

Tags: laravel-4

I got a weird redirect not working if I put the redirect outside the action. for example :

below code is working

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

public function index()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        $this->user_id = Auth::id();
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }

    // code after check
}
```

but if I take it out like below, the redirect won't work. It doesn't redirect at all.

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

public function index()
{
    $this->authorize();        
    // code after check
}

private function authorize()
{
    if (Auth::check())
    {
        $this->user_id = Auth::id();
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

Now if I have to keep using if statement in every action, it will be troublesome. Instead, I will need to call just $this->authorize();

Any idea why it wouldn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the result of "return Redirect::to('/');"

Try this:

```
public function index()
{
    return $this->authorize();        
}
```

Comment: Uppss, It is actually working with your solution. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Just an extra. It seems to be a bad way if I am using the idea of my question. Laravel actually provide routes protection. So, now I change my code with following step :

in app/filter.php change the redirect to which routes you want.

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('/');
});
```

In your route protect use following code :
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    // The list of routes you want to protect with authentication
    Route::get('blabla', 'BlablaController@index');
}
```

Remove the authorize function on BlablaController

On index function change it as follow :

```
public function index()
{
    $this->user_id = Auth::id();

    // code after check
}
```

Now it will automatically redirect to '/' if its not authenticated

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The auth filter is the best way to implement authentication.

Also, you can make your routes.php easier to read if you use the 'Route:when' to set your filters, like this:

```
Route::when('path/*', 'auth');
```

With this, you can minimize writing array('before' => 'auth') on your Route statements.